# OOP in Java - What can getters be used for?

Tags: java, object-oriented, getters

Usually, getters always return the value of a variable. I learned in my literature that access to fields is controlled by getters and setters. When I had my code rated by programmers, it was suddenly said that getters and setters violate object-oriented thinking.

So far, I have always set the output-statements in the method of a class that made changes to the object. However, if I want to change the way I make outputs (for example graphically or in a terminal), I would have to rewrite all classes. Therefore, I have considered doing the following: The output is no longer realized in the class, but the class provides methods that provide the values to be displayed. Another class is then created for display, which uses special getters to query the state of the object and display the data as it pleases. The getters are in the class that has this data. For example, I could have a "Human" object. The Human has amongst other things the variables lifeCurrent and lifeMax. These fields represent the health, if you set these values in relation. Another class called "Display" is now responsible for displaying the current health of a Human. So I would create a getter "getHealth" in the Human-Class that returns a list with lifeCurrent and lifeMax. the Display-class would have a function called health(Human). This function calls the getter from the Human and displays the values for the user of the program. Is it an accepted style to use getters like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names you give to program entities shows what you think about them, and that doesn't seem to be straight (if I understand your description correctly):

- Instances of `Human` represent human beings, and that's good.
- A method `getHealth()` returning a list of `lifeCurrent` and `lifeMax` implies that a "health" **is** a pair of `lifeCurrent` and `lifeMax`. That's strange. To me, a health would be **a number** that can be calculated from `lifeCurrent` and `lifeMax` (if that's your model world's assumption). So, `getHealth()` should do that computation and return the result. [If you say "give me a car" to someone, you don't want to get a kit without instructions, you want the end product].
- It's good to separate business logic and user interface, as you do it with `Human` (business logic) and `Display` (user interface).
- A class name of `Display` confuses me. Class names should be nouns, so I'd read that as e.g. a TFT display, which is not what you meant. A better name would be `Presenter`. And different instances of `Presenter` might show the result on different media, or in different formats.
- A method name of `health(Human)` is too unspecific. What does it do about the health? `printHealth` would be a better name. And I'd expect a `printHealth()` method to accept a health parameter (a number) instead of a `Human`. I'd expect a print method accepting a `Human` to print all information about that `Human`.

Comment: It pays not to make claims about things that are too strict. For example, the difference between `Display` and `Presenter` is not whether they are nouns, but that the latter has a suffix `-er` which implies an *agent* noun (and therefore implies something more about its particular role here). Also, I don't agree that `printHealth(human)` is less clear than `printHealth(healthParameter)`, if `printHealth` belongs to a set of methods (such as a `HumanPresenter`) that operate on `Humans`. Nor must a `Health` be a single value rather than two - it would all depend, and may be printed as two values

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **no**. As soon you define any method that returns an instance variable in any form for the sole purpose of having that information on the other side, you are smearing responsibilities all over your application, violating encapsulation and all sorts of other things.

Now the question becomes: Do you have a *reason* to invite all those bad things? If yes, then there might be a reason to have getters too.

One of the reasons could be that you have a natural boundary (of the business domain), and you don't (can't!) know what happens on the other side. So, if you don't know how it will be displayed by some other developers, then you need to publish all the data. If you *do* know how it will be presented, then that presentation (an abstract part of it) belongs in the object (as to avoid getters).

So the question is, why do you want to change the output method. Is it really a requirement to be able to change it any time? Or will it be changed one time and probably never again?